# Joomla 3x Homepage 404 & configuration file error

Tags: joomla3.0

I've started getting a 404 error on my homepage, yet I can still access the admin area.

Another issue I'm having (which I'm guessing is related) is that I cannot save any changes to the 'Global configuration' page and I get this message when I click save:

'An error has occurred.
0 Could not write to the configuration file'

The configuration.php file permission is set to 0644

This is the website URL: http://www.asgdesign.eu

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What has changed recently? Has the website been moved, for example?

Answer (score 0):

**1. htaccess**

Check the `.htaccess` file, if you have one in the root folder of your website. If there are no obvious issues, try backing up `.htaccess` and copying the default `htaccess.txt` file to `.htaccess` to see if this helps.

**2. SEF**

Temporarily disable any third party SEF extensions that are installed.

**3. Cache**

Try clearing and purging the cache to ensure you are viewing the latest version of the website.

Comment: I've managed to write to the configuration file now, but the home page is still giving me a 404 error. The debug says the article is missing. 

The site is active and when I manage to log in and I'm on a page, I click the edit page icon, but it gives me a 'page does not exist' message.

The same goes if I'm in the admin area and I select an article from the list to edit, I get this message:

An error has occurred.
0 Cannot open file for writing log